# Does economically-lucrative equaled as a prosperous economy?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

When you want to improve your English, but you cannot find the result on Google, could someone please tell me the word meaning of this:

> An **economically-lucrative** nation provides an improved standard of living its citizens.

To

> An **economically-prosperous** nation provides an improved standard of living its citizens.

This is a word meaning because I am not sure of the word economically-lucrative...

Comment: Can you give us the source? Where did you find this?

Comment: The first sentence was from an audiobook "deep work" by Cal Newport, while the second is my construction. I forgot the exact section where I heard the colloquial term as for the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at the definitions.

From Cambridge:

> **Economically**: in a way that relates to a country's trade, industry, and money
>
> - *Economically the country has been improving steadily these past ten years.*
> - ***economically depressed/backward/disadvantaged*** The neighborhood is one of Lexington's most economically depressed areas.
> - ***economically powerful/prosperous/developed*** → [note the usage "economically prosperous"]
>
> **Prosperous**: rich and successful, usually by earning a lot of money
>
> - *In a prosperous country like this, no one should go hungry.*
> - ***a prosperous country/economy/future***
>
> **Lucrative**: (especially of a business, job, or activity) [earning or] producing a lot of money
>
> - *He gave up a lucrative career as a lawyer to look after his kids.*
> - *The contest for this potentially lucrative market has been intense.*
> - ***extremely/highly/very lucrative*** This business is highly lucrative.

I personally find your original phrase

> An economically-lucrative nation ...

a bit unusual. I don't know why there is a "hyphen" there - I don't see the point. I can't find a reliable, authoritative source online (in google news and books) that says *"lucrative nation"*. "Lucrative" is usually used when talking about a business, a career, a job, a market, an opportunity, a deal, etc.

I think the better option here is what you propose - "prosperous nation". "Prosperous" is often used to describe a nation/country/region that is really doing well in terms of its economic growth (again, there shouldn't be any hyphen or dash).

> *"France is the second largest economy within the EU “euro zone,” and is generally considered to be an **economically prosperous nation** ..."* - [Harvard Divinity School](https://rlp.hds.harvard.edu/for-educators/country-profiles/france/economic-policies-ideologies)
>
> *"Switzerland is also world famous as a politically neutral and **economically prosperous nation**."* - [Marathon Tourism in Europe's Capitals](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xNtHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA243&dq=%22economically%20prosperous%20nation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL8tih8PrlAhVvIDQIHXDIAMIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22economically%20prosperous%20nation%22&f=false)

See this Google Ngram that shows the usage between *["lucrative nation" and "prosperous nation"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lucrative%20country%2Clucrative%20region%2Cprosperous%20country%2C%20prosperous%20nation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clucrative%20country%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clucrative%20region%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprosperous%20country%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprosperous%20nation%3B%2Cc0)*.

Comment: That "economically lucrative" thing comes from an audiobook "deep work" by cal newport. I just heard it and the author is a native English speaker. I am asking this because it sounds colloquial and therefore good for my English. :) but it seems that it should be used.

Comment: @JohnArvin At the end of the day, its really up to you if you want to use that term. You can ask about this in the ELL chat and see if others can comment. For me, that combination doesn't seem common usage.